# How can I remove the subject line when sending an MMS to iOS Messages?

Tags: twilio

I'm sending MMS through the Twilio REST API (i.e. sending a POST request with the MediaUrl parameter as per the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages)). When sending the message to an iPhone number, I see a "No Subject" text bubble. 
["No Subject" text bubble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfqTf.jpg)

Is there a way to edit the subject field? Or better yet, is it possible to send an MMS with no subject?

Here's my Node.JS code:

```
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken); 

client.messages.create({ 
    to: myNum, 
    from: twilioNum,
    mediaUrl: "http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg"  
}, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid); 
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Chloe, would it be possible for you to copy and paste your code into your question? I've never experienced that before and need a little more context to try and understand what might be happening.

Comment: Hey Megan, I added a code snippet. However, I've been doing some more research and I think my issue might actually be an iOS feature. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chloe, thanks for the code addition. Just ran it myself to my iOS device and I only receive the image as expected.

You can turn off the subject line feature in your phone to prevent the destination number from seeing the subject line. [Here are some tips](http://www.solveyourtech.com/remove-subject-line-messages-iphone/) on how to turn off the subject line for iPhone.

But if you're seeing this from [MMS sent via Twilio's API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages), because we currently do not support editing or declaring the subject, there's no way to add a subject or remove that `<no subject>` message from our side, so on newer smart phones that have started to display a subject won't display it.